# What causes a "The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity" error?

Tags: javascript, xml, apigee

```
{
    "code" : "messaging.config.beans.ImportFailed",
    "message" : "Failed to import the bundle : com.apigee.repository.RepositoryException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException\n - with linked exception:\n[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.]",
    "contexts" : [ ],   "cause" : {
        "message" : "javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException\n - with linked exception:\n[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.]",
        "contexts" : [ ],
        "cause" : {
            "contexts" : [ ],
            "cause" : {
                "message" : "The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.",
                "contexts" : [ ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I keep receiving this error every time I try to upload to apigee. I've checked almost every ampersand there is. Does anyone know how to get some more information?

Comment: Can you post the XML of your bundle?

Comment: All XML's validate perfectly. I have about 21 different XML's and its proving difficult to determine which one the error is in

Answer (score 2):

Check your Conditions and Conditional Flows for && -- while you can successfully deploy using && in the UI (because it helps you by converting convert "&&" to "and") you cannot use double ampersands if you deploy directly through the Management API.

Deploying this via the UI

```
<Condition>(1 = 1) && (2 = 2)</Condition>
```

will appear to succeed, but if you check your code afterwards (you may have to refresh) you'll see it becomes

```
<Condition>(1 = 1) and (2 = 2)</Condition>
```

However, if you try to deploy with the && via the management API you get the error:

```
{
  "code" : "messaging.config.beans.ImportFailed",
  "message" : "Failed to import the bundle : com.apigee.repository.RepositoryException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException\n - with linked exception:\n[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.]",
  "contexts" : [ ],
  "cause" : {
    "message" : "javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException\n - with linked exception:\n[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.]",
    "contexts" : [ ],
    "cause" : {
      "contexts" : [ ],
      "cause" : {
        "message" : "The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.",
        "contexts" : [ ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have discovered that you can also get this error uploading the bundle via the UI -- so only editing in the UI and saving directly from that editor will change && to and

Comment: Great point Michael -- my normal programming inclination would be to use && and ||, but this is definitely a reason to stick with AND and OR in conditions.

Answer (score 1):

By far the most common cause of this parsing error is an unencoded ampersand somewhere in the XML's text. You'll need to encode the ampersand in the XML. You can do this with `&amp;` or `&#038;` (the Unicode equivalent for the ampersand), or you might be able to embed it inside a `CDATA` section.

You say that you've checked almost every ampersand there is -- besides the obvious recommendation to check the rest of them, if you are using parameters in an XSL transformation, I'd make sure the data you are sending in doesn't have unencoded ampersands. You might need to run a JavaScript or other code policy to encode any ampersands in your input parameters before the transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Its been resolved. An ampersand had been included in the properties file therefore during the maven build process the ampersand would be included in the XML in the final zip/jar file.

Easy to make mistake.